# Proper Schema.org markup for product reviews - that are blog posts

Tags: blogs, schema.org, review

What's the proper Schema.org JSON-LD for a blog post / article that is solely meant to be a review for a product? Example of a practical usage that's ubiqutous on the web: I own a website that has a blog writing reviews and providing affiliate links (for example Amazon).

Technically, this is a `Product`, it's a `Review`, and obviously it's an `Article` (`BlogPosting`?).

On the `Product` you can nest the `Review` structure. So, this seems to be more focused with the pages content and this is the one I would assume is to be used. But, it is still an article and technically the site doesn't offer the product itself making the `Product` type seem incorrect.

So how exactly are you supposed to handle affiliate markup like this for blog sites without getting potentially dinged for marking up misleading information?

Comment: "technically the site doesn't offer the product itself making the `Product` type seem incorrect": It’s [perfectly fine](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/117714/17633) to use `Product` for things you don’t sell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how expressive you want to be. For consumers interested in reviews, the first snippet would typically be all they need, as it’s likely not relevant to them if the review is published as blog post, as article, as forum post etc.

---

The minimum would be a [`Review`](https://schema.org/Review) with [`itemReviewed`](https://schema.org/itemReviewed):

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Product"
  }
}
```

If you want to convey that the review is published as a blog post, you could use [`BlogPosting`](https://schema.org/BlogPosting) in addition:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": ["Review", "BlogPosting"],
  "itemReviewed": {
    "@type": "Product"
  }
}
```

If the `BlogPosting` consists of more than just the `Review`, but the `Review` is the primary content, you could use [`mainEntity`](https://schema.org/mainEntity) with separate entities (and if it’s not the primary entity, you could use [`hasPart`](https://schema.org/hasPart) instead):

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "BlogPosting",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "Review",
    "itemReviewed": {
      "@type": "Product"
    }
  }
}
```

And if you want to provide data about the web page which contains the blog posting which is/contains the review, you could use [`ItemPage`](https://schema.org/ItemPage) with `mainEntity`:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "ItemPage",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": ["Review", "BlogPosting"],
    "itemReviewed": {
      "@type": "Product"
    }
  }
}
```

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "ItemPage",
  "mainEntity": {
    "@type": "BlogPosting",
    "mainEntity": {
      "@type": "Review",
      "itemReviewed": {
        "@type": "Product"
      }
    }
  }
}
```